# Mi sitio web está sirviendo URL'S de una forma errónea

Tags: php, mysql, uri

¡Hola! El día de ayer, monitoreando a los visitantes de mi sitio web por medio de Google Analytics, encontré un problema en mi sitio web.

En mi sitio web muestro contenido a través de URL's como esta:

`https://mywebsite.com/post.php?id=2931`

Pero por agluna razón, si agrego carácteres extra al final de la URL original como en este ejemplo:

`https://mywebsite.com/post.php?id=2931asnfiasdno3enjlanaisd`

Mi sitio web sigue mostrando el contenido de esta URL:

`https://mywebsite.com/post.php?id=2931`

¿Esto es algo normal? Y si no, ¿Cómo puedo prevenir que esto suceda, redireccionando a mis visitantes a alguna página de error cuando alguien agregue carácteres extra a la URL original?

### Mi sitio web está programado en PHP y mi información la almaceno en MySQL.

Así es como recojo la información para ser mostrada:

Primero declaro la variable id:

`$id = htmlspecialchars(addslashes(stripslashes(strip_tags(trim(@$_GET['id'])))));`

Después hago la consulta a MySQL:

```
$queryPost = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$resultPost = $mysqli->query($queryPost);
$Post = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPost, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$post_status = $Post['id'];
....
```

Y finalmente imprimo la información que necesito.

También, implemento un código para verificar si el usuario del cuál se está mostrando un post, tiene un "Username" configurado en su cuenta, para redirigir al usuario a una URL amigable tipo

```
https://misitioweb.com/nombredeusuario/post/id-del-post
```

Y esa redirección la hago mediante este código:

```
if(!@$_GET['username']){
include 'process/if_username.php';    
if($if_username){ 
    
$param = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
function removeGetParam($param){
 $params = $_GET;

 // removing the key
 unset($params[$param]); 

 // joining and returning the rest
 return implode('&', array_map(function ($value, $key) { 
            return $key.'='.$value;
          },$params, array_keys($params))
        );
}

$filtered_params = removeGetParam('id');
if(!empty($filtered_params)){ $filtered_params = "?".$filtered_params; }
header("Location:/".$if_username."/post/".$post_id.$filtered_params, true, 301);
    
}
}
```

Sin embargo este código solamente se ejecuta si en la URL existe el parametro `$_GET['username'];`

Y en la URL original no existe ese parámetro:

`https://mywebsite.com/post.php?id=2931`

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega código PHP de cómo recoges el valor y cómo lo usas para hacer la consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, añadí ya información adicional :)

Comment: en principio la dirección que muestras es post.php la parte ?id=xxxxxx simplemente está estableciendo el valor de la clave 'id' en la superglobal $_GET de modo que no importa que pongas ahí, va a ser atendido por post.php y es allí donde se decide que se hace con el valor xxxxxxx establecido para id

Comment: Gracias por responder @quevedo sin embargo eso debería traerme solamente el registro que tenga en la base de datos el id con ese valor exactamente... ¿No?

En mi base de datos sí existe un registro con el id "2931" pero no existe un registro con el id "2931asnfiasdno3enjlanaisd" y aún así me muestra la información del id "2931".

Comment: Si es así, debes revisar la consulta porque no usas sentencias preparadas y eres vulnerable a inyección SQL, la cola despues del 2931, si está separada por "; puede hacer lo que quiera en tu BD y de repente en el servidor

Comment: Ojo: `$queryPost = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$id'";` es justo lo que necesita un atacante para hacer inyección sql. Tu método para sanear variables no es suficiente. Consulta [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia de Prepared Statements y PDO, supongo que esas son las consecuencias de aprender de libros escritos hace años jaja, mientras adapto todo mi código web, hay alguna de blindar de una mejor manera estas consultas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creí que no iba a funcionar la prueba que hice en PhpMyAdmin, pero efectivamente, al parecer se hace un cast a entero del valor recibido y funciona. Se necesitan algunas validaciones para solucionar esto:

```
// Obtienes ID
$id = htmlspecialchars(addslashes(stripslashes(strip_tags(trim(@$_GET['id'])))));
// Convertir a entero
$id = intval($id);
// Asegúrate no sea menor o igual que cero
if($id <= 0) {
    // Deberías lanzar un error, producto no encontrado
}
// Asegúrate de que es igual al parámetro proporcionado
if(!strcmp("$id", $_GET['id'])) {
    // El $id numérico no es igual a lo proporcionado por parámetro
    // Encabezado para evitar que buscadores indexen y preparar para redirigir
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    // Redirigir a página correcta:
    header("Location: https://mywebsite.com/post.php?id=$id");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte!! intenté con la función intval() para revisar la variable GET; pero sigue sin redirigir si el valor no tiene solamente un id numérico.

Comment: Prueba con `strcmp()` para comparar ambos valores como cadena, ahora debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias! funcionó :)